# Using System.Linq in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view

I have a db structure as follows

```
FeedbackTable      
   Id
   Name
   ...
   ...

ProjectApprovalTable
    Id
    FeedbackId
    ...
    ...
```

I am passing `FeedbackDetails` to the view.How can I access `projectapproval details` in the view.

This is what I have tried

```
 if (Model.StudentFeedback[i].IsTrainerVerified == true && Model.StudentFeedback[i].StudentProjectApprovals.FirstOrDefault().IsTrainerApproved == false)
 {
  ...
 }
```

Here I am getting error `No Extension Method for FirstOrDefault()`

**The Model Class is**

```
 public partial class StudentFeedback
{
    public StudentFeedback()
    {
        this.StudentProjectApprovals = new HashSet<StudentProjectApproval>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<StudentProjectApproval> StudentProjectApprovals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to show you actual models. Is `StudentProjectApprovals` a collection property (and have you included the `using` statements)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Yes you are right `StudentProjectApprovals` is a collection property.Not quite got what you meant by `using` statements.

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I have added System.Data.Linq in the project and tried                   `@using System.Data.Linq` in the view ,but I am still getting `assembly reference error`

Comment: `System.Linq;` is not `System.Data.Linq`

Comment: I tried `System.Linq` but still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105111/discussion-between-ksg-and-stephen-muecke).